# Getting parent node p even if there is another tag inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to adds a class to the p tags to `.content` contenteditable div (based on the position of the caret):

```
var $content = $('.content'),
    $p = $content.find('p');

$content.on('keyup click', function(e) {
    var focusElement = window.getSelection().baseNode.parentElement;
    $p.removeClass('hover');
    $(focusElement).addClass('hover');
});
```

It works fine with structures like this:

```
<p>Text text</p>
<p class="hover">Text text</p>
```

the problem arises with structures like this:

```
<p>Text text</p>
<p>Text <i>text</i></p>
```

Any html tag inside `p` seems to disrupt the code, preventing it from adding the `hover` class to the `p` tag.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You could just use: `$(focusElement).closest('p').addClass('hover');` as `.closest()` includes element itself

Comment: You dont close the i tag correct. <i>text<i/> should be <i>text</i>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content.on('keyup click', function(e) {
    $(window.getSelection().baseNode).closest('p').addClass('hover');
    $p.removeClass('hover');
});
```